# I want to make disk Partition for my hard disk

Tags: 14.04, disk, playonlinux

I want to install **Ubuntu** on my laptop as a **main or primary** operating system without Windows or anything else. My hard disk size is **300 G.B**, I have two questions :
**first** : What is the best or ideal size partitioning for the hard disk? 
**Second**: How I can do that, please use pictures if you can?

Comment: Use the following link to partition your hard-drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352

Comment: My laptop Ram is 4G.B and I have windows 7 on the laptop, I want to remove it and I was backup all my data on external USB hard drive, now I want to install Ubuntu as a primary OS for my laptop replace of windows 7, and I want to know how to partition hard disk through install Ubuntu and what is the ideal size partitioning for the hard disk and how to remove the old partitioning

Comment: Sincerely, make a 2 GB swap partition and leave the rest in a single partition. This way you'll avoid frequent "low disk space" problems.

Comment: Case 1: My hard drive is 300 GB I will do that ( / >> 100 GB) - (/boot --> 1GB) - (/tmp --> 8 GB) - (swap --> 8GB) - (/home --> 100GB) , So that' mean the remain will be 83 GB for /ed1 or else.

Comment: Case 2: My hard drive is 300 GB I will do that ( / >> 100 GB) - (/boot --> 1GB) - (/tmp --> 8 GB) - (swap --> 8GB) - (/home --> 150GB for all my data) , So that' mean the remain will be 33 GB for /ed1 or else like VM and rest of my data

Comment: Which case is good for me and why? and if the system crash for any reason do I will lose my data on /home or not , and my data on /ed1 will be safe if system crash?

Answer (score 1):

1. /      --> 100GB
2. /boot  --> 1GB
3. /tmp   --> Double the ram size
4. swap --> Double the ram size
5. /home  --> 100GB

For the reaming size create any folder like
        /ed1 --> whatever size reaming have

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34805/discussion-on-answer-by-kanagaraj-kanagaraj-i-want-to-make-disk-partition-for-m).

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends. if your hard disk is partitioned before and you have data on it you have to make an additional space for your Ubuntu. The size of this particular partition is based on what you're going to do with your OS & how much free space you have, but I suggest at least 30 GB.
If your disk if fresh and not partitioned you can have all of it as the root partition of the OS. (you need a few gigabytes for swap.)
For the the second question you can use a bootable DVD or flash of Ubuntu or Linux Mint! after booting from USB flash open GParted and you can use it to creat, delete and move any partition you wish!

Comment: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

See Sadegh Ghasemi answer.

Find your amount of RAM (I have 8GB), You need to create a Swap Partition of at least this size.
Then Create an ext4 partition for root (Linux-Ubuntu) of 20 or more GB - if you want to have your Home on a separate partition, I have chosen to have my Home on the shared with the root, remember to set mountpoint to root!
[image]
Remember to press the Apply Button (Checkmark) to write your settings to the disk!
Happy Ubunting :-)

Answer (score 0):

My dear, the best partitioning in my view is: 25GB ext4 / dev/sda1, mount point/, 275 GB ext4/ dev/sda5 mount point /home and 4GB Swap /dev/sda6.

This 25 GB partition, should be the --boot system (single primary partition on the disk).
This 275 will be mounted on / home (logical partition) if you want to update the kernel or change the linux OS, user data will not be affected.
And the logical partition with 4GB Swap will be essential for this to work

You must use the bootable CD or USB drive, choose manual partitioning - assisted instead of using the whole disk.